# Need transistor power amplifying stage scheme

Tags: transistors, amplifier, lm386

i'm doing audio amplifier for my bachelors degree in physics. I have to simulate it all in Multisim. And i'm all out of ideas.
First i've used simple LM386 amp scheme, but it doesn't give enough power. I need 2nd stage to connect to output of LM386 scheme to make out power about 20W.
Please help, any ideas are welcome. [image: I'm using the one on the right]

Comment: Google '20W audio amplifier chips' works for me.

Comment: The LM386 is not really suitable as the driver stage for a higher power amplifier. And if it's part of a degree course, you probably want to show you can research and implement existing circuits and not just throw an IC on a PCB.

Comment: People are down voting why? Cause op doesn't know the answer? Which is why they are asking on a Q & A site?

Comment: I think people are down voting because the OP did very little research into the problem and because a "cookbook" solution to an academic problem doesn't help in understanding the subject matter.

Answer (score 5):

Since you're all out of ideas, maybe you can wow them with a circuit description for this, hot off the press and into the 1970 RCA Receiving Tube Manual.

[image]

Comment: I'm tempted to down vote this. It seems disingenuous as a real answer :/

Comment: This answer is awesome.  There's plenty of real physics involved and the OP might do very well with it if he could explain the properties of the vacuum tubes (valves) that allow it to operate.

Comment: @Passerby: And what?  Your puny  downvote will reduce me to rubble?  If you have a complaint, then voice it and state why you're at odds with my point of view instead  of threatening censure with authority you're lacking.

Comment: It's beautifully disingenuous but gets my vote!